# Polymer, SVG, touch events not working in Chrome 36+ (touch devices)

Tags: google-chrome, svg, polymer, touchpad

So when playing with this example:
http://jsbin.com/dopazitu/1/edit
you can see that the touch events attached to the  element (yellow rectangle) work perfectly fine, but the same events attached to an SVG element (red circle) don't work at all.

It works fine on:
desktop browsers,
Opera (touch device)

It won't work on Sony touchpad, with either Chrome 36.0.1985.128 or Chrome Beta 37.0.2062.39

does anyone know why, or know some sort of work-around for this issue?

Comment: all the mouse events appear to work fine mouseup, mousedown

Comment: You might want to create this as a bug on [`polymer-gestures`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-gestures/issues)

Answer (score 0):

This was supposedly patched in Chromium at [revision 171207](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?view=revision&revision=171207):

> Update touch-action hit-testing to match latest spec changes. touch-action now applies to all elements with both width AND height properties.
>
> Also fix application to SVG elements.
>
> BUG=[356215](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=356215), [247396](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=247396)
>
> Review URL: https://codereview.chromium.org/220343002

You might want to raise a bug on the chromium tracker if you have found a regression.